# window does not close with close() method

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

Very strange problem but still do not understand why.
I have a grid and on ColumnDblClick i open a window.
Window works fine, submit data but when try to close window, it does not close.

```
saveRefresh : function() {

            this.win.close(); <---------------------------execute fine.

            this.grid.getView().refresh();
    },
```

Above coding works fine and does not raise any error. It refresh grid and grid shows saved data.
But some how it does not close window.
I have to click "Save" button 3 times to close window.

Any idea why it follow strange behaviour??

Many Thanks.

Comment: Does win have any logic when closing. Validate, save etc?

Comment: No, there is no listener added on to it. It is just ordinary window.

Comment: Don't know extjs, but i'd look at things like hiding the window, and perhaps setting win and any other reference to it to null.

Comment: @extjsuser Please post your window config object.

Answer (score 1):

We always use window.hide().  It makes more sense in almost all cases anyway:

```
saveRefresh : function() {

    this.win.hide();

    this.grid.getView().refresh();
}
```